# Question about mirror glazes and freezing

Tags: cake, glaze

I'm trying my hand at a layered mousse cake with a mirror glaze (I guess this is an entremet?). I've read several places that it is advisable to freeze the cake prior to glazing. My question is then: am I supposed to eat the cake frozen? Seems like it would be hard? Or should I let it thaw in the refrigerator? If so, for how long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to glaze the cake when it's only just frozen: a couple hours should do, all you want is for the surface to be cold enough to fix the glaze in place.
 Once you've glazed it, leave it in the fridge just a few minutes, mousse doesn't take long to defrost.

Comment: Hmm, [this recipe](https://chefiso.com/p/white-chocolate-mirror-glaze-recipe/) says "First, ensure you have a completely frozen cake, which means keeping your cake in the freezer overnight.? Different schools? :)

Comment: You wanna freeze it a couple hours, overnight is just unnecessary. All you want is fo the surface to be cold enough to fix the glaze in place

Comment: @TQ1000 it would be good if you could include the reason and how that works in the answer, so it doesn’t get lost if comments get deleted.